# Disabling user/register

Tags: users

I want to disable the user/register page in Drupal 7 but I still want registrations possible, but only through other links. I've tried altering the access to it through a module like so:

```
my_module_menu_alter(&$items) {
     $items['user/register']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
```

but it does not seem to work. I know I can alter the form permission and set it to false but I need the form for other modules I have installed. Is there any way to do this with a already existing module or programmatically?

Comment: `&items`...that's not a variable...I'm surprised that even runs

Comment: The spambots will eventually find your other links, so this isn't going to be as useful as you might think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation is most probably correct, I use the following code to customize access to the register page in some projects:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/register']['access callback'] = 'MYMODULE_user_register_access';
  unset($items['user/register']['access arguments']);
  $items['user/register']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
}
```

Make sure that the custom module is enabled, make sure that the module name is spelled correctly, also make sure that there really is an `&` prepended to the `$items` parameter. It happened to me in the past that I forgot the reference operator on `hook_X_alter` implementations. Also flush caches after adding new hook implementation functions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing this with configuration itself. Go to `admin/config/people/accounts`. Under Registration and Cancellation find out Who can register account?
 and set it to Administrator.

https://docs.google.com/a/srijan.in/file/d/0B9FG53CLjf-YeW9XcEs0SjRBcDQ/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Don't you get it? I want people to register through another form, I don't want mo make accounts manually. This is not viable!

Comment: Another form submit handler wouldn't be affected by this configuration and still user will be able to register through it.

Comment: If it would be entirely custom then I would agree with you. The other modules call the internal register form from Drupal. In this case it would not work. 
  
I thank for your for your feedback.